# What argument does my function need to echo get_results() query results

Tags: wp-query, functions, wpdb, sql

This is my database query:

```
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'qs_css';
$db_css = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT qs_the_css 
    FROM $table_name
    WHERE qs_css_id = 1 
    "
);

echo $db_css[0]->qs_the_css;  // works just fine
```

However, I need the query results inside my function:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'quick_qs_db_css', 100 );
function quick_qs_db_css(  ) { ?>

<style type="text/css" id="db-css">
<?php echo $db_css[0]->qs_the_css; //outputs null ?>
</style>

<?php }
```

What arguments does the `quick_qs_db_css()` function need ? Is it possible to pass query results to a function?

Any input would be very much appreciated !  Thanking in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just do..

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'quick_qs_db_css', 100 );
function quick_qs_db_css() { ?>
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'qs_css';
    $db_css = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "
        SELECT qs_the_css 
        FROM $table_name
        WHERE qs_css_id = 1 
        "
    );
    <style type="text/css" id="db-css">
    <?php echo $db_css[0]->qs_the_css; //outputs null ?>
    </style>

<?php }
```

Seeing as you are using it everytime head is loaded, it would make more sense than to keep the two separate unless there's good reason for it?

Comment: Thanks Steve, well I need to fetch the CSS twice on the same page.  That's t why  I don't to repeat myself ...

Comment: Okay so seperate them into two functions. Instead of echo on the CSS, use return. Then call the function inside of the quick_qs_db_css and assign it to a variable you can use to echo the result.

Comment: @Stever North, Thank you !   Works perfectly :)   Really appreciate your input.